# Update Flutter ListTile with tap not working

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, boolean, dart-pub

The goal is to change the values in the ListTile of **leading** and **subtitle** to ***null*** on tap. The tap is switching the **_act** boolean, but the ListTile's leading: and subtitle: values do not change from their initial state. My code for the ListView is below. Please help.

```
        return new ListView(
          children: querySnapShot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            bool _act = false;
            return new ListTile(
              leading: _act != false ? const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye, color: Color(0xff00caff), size: 40) : null,
              title: new Text((DBProvider.db.idDeHasher(document['exampleid'], key) ?? 'fallback'), style: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor)),
              subtitle: _act != false ? new Text((document['exampleString']  ?? 'fallbackString'), style: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor)) : null,
              onTap: () { 
                _act = !_act;
                print(_act.toString());
                }
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Comment: Use `setState` to change the `_act`.

Comment: The _act variable gets reset to false on every setState due to it's instantiation being inside the ListView widget. Instantiating the _act variable in the state class ittself will provide the update and change the values, but every row in the listview will be updated rather than the single row tapped, as they will then all use the same _act value. @Mobina

Comment: What do you expect to happen without updating the state? Nothing will change. You can store a list of `act`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your widget a `Stateful Widget` and call `setState` when there is a tap on the `ListTile`.

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html):

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

So if the state of the widget changes **you have** to call `setState` to trigger a rebuild of the view and see immediatly the changes implied by the new state.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
     // define a list of acts
        List _acts = [];
         return new ListView(
          children: querySnapShot.data.documents.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
          // declare all entries of the list to false
          acts.add(false);
          // access the index 
          int index = entry.key;
          // access the document
          DocumentSnapshot document = entry.value;
          // DocumentSnapshot document = entry
            return new ListTile(
              leading: _acts[index] != false ? const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye, color: Color(0xff00caff), size: 40) : null,
              title: new Text((DBProvider.db.idDeHasher(entry.val['exampleid'], key) ?? 'fallback'), style: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor)),
              subtitle: _acts[index] != false ? new Text((document['exampleString']  ?? 'fallbackString'), style: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor)) : null,
              onTap: () { 
               // call setstate
              setState(() { // new line
              // change the bool variable based on the index
               _acts[index] = !_acts[index];
                print(_acts[index].toString());
              });
                }
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Comment: I tried this once before. The _act variable gets reset to false on every setState due to it's instantiation being inside the ListView widget. Instantiating the _act variable in the state class ittself will provide the update and change the values, but every row in the listview will be updated rather than the single row tapped, as they will then all use the same _act value.

Comment: Trying to get this working. Getting errors on the first line and every index. "Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.
Try adding a selector." and "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void."

Comment: Made a huge mistake with the code, you can check it now.

Comment: This worked! Just had to change entry.val to document and instantiate List _acts = []; in the state class. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () { 
setState((){
                _act = !_act;
                print(_act.toString());
                }
});
```

Just copy and paste this, it will work.

Comment: I tried this once before. The _act variable gets reset to false on every setState due to it's instantiation being inside the ListView widget. Instantiating the _act variable in the state class ittself will provide the update and change the values, but every row in the listview will be updated rather than the single row tapped, as they will then all use the same _act value.

Answer (score 0):

replace `bool _act = false;` just below

`class _SomeClass extends State<SomeClass> {`
and surround with `setState({});`